# managing 2 npm lib releases - of the same lib - in one registry?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration

One of our apps (my-app) dependencies is an npm lib we publish to npm (my-lib).

```
name: my-app;
version: <my-app-version>
dependencies: {
   my-lib: <my-lib-version>
}
```

As a company we are committed to support the current version and 1 older version.
my-app 1.0.0 depends on my-lib 1.0.0

```
 name: my-app;
 version: 1.0.0
 dependencies: {
   my-lib: 1.0.0
 }
```

my-app 2.0.0 depends on latest my-lib which is 3.1.0

```
 name: my-app;
 version: 2.0.0
 dependencies: {
   my-lib: 3.1.0
 }
```

We have a bug in my-lib which we must fix for **both**.
The easy thing to do would be fixing in 3.1.0,
but my-app 1.0.0 can't adopt 3.1.0 as it introduces breaking changes, and must stay in version 1.X.X.
What's the standard way to fix my-lib in both?

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to update both `1.x.x` and `3.x.x` versions, you might keep working on 2 separated GIT branches and publish 2 separate patch releases on NPM.

Comment: but npm doesn't allow to publish patches for old version; once you have version 2.X.X you can't publish something to 1.X.X.

Comment: Hi Mattan,

You should be able to publish to older versions without problems. I've tested this against an npmE installation with both the 3.x and 5.x version of the npm CLI.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @MattanBitner as far as I know, you can't override EXISTING older versions but, even I didn't tried yet, reading npm documentation, I think I understood that you can publish patches to older versions. So, for instance, if your last 1.x.x version was 1.1.3, then you should be able to publish 1.1.4 even existing 2.0.0 or 3.0.0 versions.